# reverse print using recursion

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I just started with recursion and couldn't seem to understand how the following will happen.
I want to print the values from `i = 2` to `i = 6`. currently, it is printing in reverse order. Could you please help me?

```
int l[][7] ={{0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,2,1,1,2},{0,0,1,2,1,2,2}};
int lstar = 1;
int recprint(int n, int i){
    if (i>n)
    {
        return lstar;
    }
    else{
        int m =  recprint(n, i+1);
        printf("i is %d and l[%d][%d] is %d \n", i, m, i , l[m][i]);
        return l[m][i];
    }
}
recprint(6, n);
```

output required is

```
i is 6 and l[1][6] is 2     
i is 5 and l[2][5] is 2     
i is 4 and l[2][4] is 1     
i is 3 and l[1][3] is 2      
i is 2 and l[2][2] is 1
```

in reverse

Comment: Trace through your program line by line and see what is happening.  Your development environment should be able to help, or else your program is short enough to trace what is happening on paper.

Comment: What is `recprint` supposed to return?

Comment: it should just print ```l[m][j]``` in reverse order. not necessary it should return something

Comment: I'm a bit confused so can you show us what the output should look like for the array in your question?

Comment: edited the question for the output requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```c++
void recprint(int i, int j, int val = 1) {
  if (i < j) {
    return;
  }
  recprint(i - 1, j, l[val][i]);
  printf("i is %d and l[%d][%d] is %d\n", i, val, i, l[val][i]);
}

recprint(6, 2);
```

Output:

```
i is 2 and l[2][2] is 1 
i is 3 and l[1][3] is 2 
i is 4 and l[2][4] is 1 
i is 5 and l[2][5] is 2 
i is 6 and l[1][6] is 2
```

Comment: Following was my problem while solving this question.
This recurring function is to print the matrix. We are printing based on a value we get ```lstar``` from the preceding function, which is kind of the last value. So we can't start from ```[2,2]```, coz we won't know if it is ```[2,2]``` we have to access or ```[1,2]```. The value that we want to calculate, ```l[val][i]```, the ```val``` we will be getting from ```l[rec(val, i+1)][i]``` till i+1 > 6 . Coz then we know the value of ```lstar```. So we can access ```l[lstar][6]```